# TypeError: Error while fetching data from PostgresSQL not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql

> TypeError: Error while fetching data from PostgresSQL not all
> arguments converted during string formatting.

Please help me

```
Main_List = [[1,12345,10.100.30.27,2020-10-09 09:45:31,12,0,0,9]]
records_to_insert= [tuple(x) for x in Main_list]

sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO dailypunch (ip_address, emp_code, datetime,number) 
                       VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) """

    
result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
```

Comment: Please add definition of your table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_testing (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,hostel_bio_metric_id varchar(100),
    date TIMESTAMP,
    ip varchar(100),
    read_status int ,is_in_valid int,att_state int,work_code int
);          @MichałAlbrycht

Answer (score 0):

Your tuple has 8 fields and you are trying to insert into table with 4 fields. Values in tuple needs to be in correct order - ip_addres should be first, emp_code second and so on. What's more your `Main_List` is not a valid list in python it lacks quotes:

```
Main_List = [[1,12345,'10.100.30.27','2020-10-09 09:45:31',12,0,0,9]]
```

Comment: ok i will add quotes also it showing the same error

Comment: how to add specify values ? please guide me @Michal

Comment: Change order of fields in your insert statement. Try something like this: `INSERT INTO dailypunch ( here_should_be_listed_8_fields_of_your_table_in_correct_order) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`